# How to turn off Location service with objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, location

I want turn on/off Location Service on Iphone with objective-c.
How to turn on/off Location Service programatically?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible, you cannot control settings within applications like bluetooth/airplane/wifi and location service.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. That's just out of your hand. You cant stop location services. One thing you can do is, you can stop updating location by using this :

```
[myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Call this method whenever your code no longer needs to receive location-related events. Disabling event delivery gives the receiver the option of disabling the appropriate hardware (and thereby saving power) when no clients need location data. You can always restart the generation of location updates by calling the startUpdatingLocation method again.

But to stop services, you have to go to settings options.